# Size column is empty in Android Studio 3.0 network profiler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I just started AS 3.0 Network Profiler for the first time. And the size column is empty. I am testing on emulator API 27. I have enabled advanced profiling in app configuration. Here is the list of libraries I use for network.

```
// Network
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Just tested on emulator API 26 and 25. On 26 the profile froze and the app stoped. On 25 the results are the same (everything is fine, but the size is empty)